# Checking whether a document present in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a nodejs application using mongodb as database. I need to check whether a username exist in mongodb or not. If username present, it will output **"username not available"**, else will list all the user details with that username.

```
var userSchema = require('../schemas/user');

exports.collect = function(req,res) {
    userSchema.find({ username: "bob" }).exec(function(err,display) { 
        if(err){
            console.log(err);

        }
        else
        {
            if(display=='[]'){
                res.send("username not available");
            }

            else{
                res.send(display)
            }

        }

    });
};
```

Is there any alternative or simple way for performing this operation?

Comment: May be `display.length === 0` is simpler, than check empty array against String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would decouple the whole logic from the controller if you ask me, but I'm not going to lecture you on that. I would use `findOne` as that will find just one record. If the `user` is not available, you will know that this username is not available. Don't forget that even when an error occurs, you still want to output "some" data, as you don't want the client to wait until it times out.

```
var userSchema = require('../schemas/user');

exports.collect = function(req,res) {
  userSchema.findOne({username: "bob"}).exec(function(err, user) { 
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);

        // Handle the error properly here, we should not continue!
        return res.sendStatus(500);
    }

    if (!user) {
      return res.send("username not available");
    }

    // Don't know what you want to do with it, I just display it like this
    return res.json(user);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was looking whether there is anyother alternatives like inbuilt functions :) But one doubt, shouldn't we add a semicolon at the end?